# Elasticsearch how to remove a field while reindexing

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to remove `data.properties.review_meta` field because it's causing trouble

```
POST /_reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "analytics-prod-2020.11.05"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "analytics-prod-2020.11.05.02"
  },

  "conflicts": "proceed",

  "script" : {
    "source": "ctx._source.data.remove('properties.review_meta')"
  }

}
```

code doesn't work with the error message

```
 "failures" : [
    {
      "index" : "analytics-prod-2020.11.05.02",
      "type" : "_doc",
      "id" : "gksugnUBaMafnb1n2Iqy",
      "cause" : {
        "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason" : "object mapping for [data.properties.review_meta] tried to parse field [review_meta] as object, but found a concrete value"
      },
      "status" : 400
    },
    {
      "index" : "analytics-prod-2020.11.05.02",
      "type" : "_doc",
      "id" : "jUsvgnUBaMafnb1nsrkC",
      "cause" : {
        "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason" : "object mapping for [data.properties.review_meta] tried to parse field [review_meta] as object, but found a concrete value"
      },
      "status" : 400
    }
  ]
```

source index(2020.11.05) has

```
            "review_meta" : {
              "type" : "long"
            },
```

dest index(2020.11.05.02) has index template

```
    {
      "review_meta" : {
        "match" : "review_meta",
        "mapping" : {
          "type" : "object"
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script should be like this instead and then it will work:

```
ctx._source.data.properties.remove('review_meta')
```

Comment: indeed, it works.. I had to add ctx._source.containsKey('data') check and along the path